# How to link Ionic 3 wtih android native code?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I've followed the tutorial with [helpstack.io](https://github.com/happyfoxinc/helpstack-android). I've successfully run the `HelpStackExample` with android native based on the [github](https://github.com/happyfoxinc/helpstack-android) given.

Unfortunately, my company project using Ionic 3.

Now, here's the problem:- 
**helpstack.io** only support android native but not with **Ionic 3**.

So, how to link **Ionic 3** with **helpstack.io** android native code?

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have Cordova plugin for `HelpStack`. But unfortunately, there is no such thing yet.So you have to write a Cordova plugin for that. After that, you can easily use that plugin with `Ionic 3` app.

Hope this helps for [**Developing a Plugin on Android**](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/plugin-development/android/)

Comment: Oh my god...I need to create a plugin for helpstack? I've never experience such thing..huhu... anyway..thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, That is the only option here for you :)